# What's the difference between LazyList and Stream in Scala?

Tags: scala, stream, scala-collections, lazylist

I noticed that `Stream` is deprecated in `Scala 2.13` and they suggest using `LazyList`.
They also say "Use LazyList (which is fully lazy) instead of Stream (which has a lazy tail only)".
What does it exactly mean ? Why did they deprecate `Stream` ?

Comment: Basically **Stream** was only lazy on its `tail`, so the `head` was always computed. For many people this was surprising and lead to erroneous code. On the other hand **LayzList** is fully lazy. It doesn't compute the head until it is called. Note that when you compute the head of a LayzList also computes its tail and viceversa.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Is there an example of erroneous code it would lead to?

Comment: @MarioGalic not erroneous in the sense of correctness. But erroneous in the sense of how it was behaving.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NthPortal, a contributor to `LazyList`, states in [Update and improve LazyList docs #7842](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7842/files#r264513994)

> The key difference between `LazyList` and `Stream` - and its key feature -
>   is that whether or not it is lazy is evaluated lazily. I'm not sure
>   how best to convey that.

jwvh states in [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59587663/5205022)

> `Stream` elements are realized lazily except for the 1st (head) element.
>   That was seen as a deficiency.

Scala 2.13 release notes [state](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0)

[`immutable.LazyList`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.html) replaces `immutable.Stream`. `Stream` had different laziness behavior and is now deprecated. ([#7558](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7558), [#7000](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7000))

Answer (score 2):

As per the [blog post](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2018/06/13/scala-213-collections.html#lazylist-is-preferred-over-stream):

> LazyList Is Preferred Over Stream
>
> Stream is deprecated in favor of LazyList. As its name suggests, a LazyList is a linked list whose elements are lazily evaluated. An important semantic difference with Stream is that in LazyList **both** the head and the tail are lazy, whereas in Stream **only the tail is lazy**.

Also in the [Stream documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html):

> Deprecated (Since version 2.13.0)
>
> Use LazyList (which is fully lazy) instead of Stream (which has a lazy tail only)