# How to generate dynamic daterange for n days in Scala

Tags: scala

I want daterange for last 'n' days as a string using Scala. Below are my inputs

**Input**:

startingDate = `"2020-08-20"`

range = 30 (days)

**Expected output:**

```
"2020-08-20,2020-08-19,2020-08-18,2020-08-17,2020-08-16,2020-08-15,2020-08-14,2020-08-13,2020-08-12,2020-08-11,2020-08-10,2020-08-19,2020-08-09,2020-08-08,2020-08-07,2020-08-06,2020-08-05,2020-08-04,2020-08-03,2020-08-02,2020-08-01,2020-07-31,2020-07-30,2020-07-29,2020-07-28,2020-07-27,2020-07-26,2020-07-25,2020-07-24,2020-07-23,2020-07-22"
```

Comment: Show some code, show your problem. This isn’t a “plz give me code” website.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [`Iterator.iterate`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator$.html#iterate%5BA%5D(start:A,len:Int)(f:A=%3EA):CC%5BA%5D) to produce a lazy sequence of dates:

```
import java.time.LocalDate

def days(start: LocalDate, step: Int): Iterator[LocalDate] =
  Iterator.iterate(start)(_.plusDays(step))
```

You can have this iterator go forward with `step > 0` or backwards with `step < 0` (or stand still with `step == 0`, but you're unlikely to want that).

In your case you can have `step = -1` to move backward one day at a time for each item in the iterator and then `.take(30)` items and `mkString` out of them:

```
val startingDate = LocalDate.parse("2020-08-20")

val output = days(start = startingDate, step = -1).take(30).mkString(",")

// output is 2020-08-20,2020-08-19,2020-08-18,2020-08-17,...
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/sZ4kbyWcRcWRNNw5BvZ3Cw/53).

Note that `Iterator`s are mutable, which means that they can't be safely shared across your code. For a purely functional alternative you can use a `LazyList`, as shown in [this Scastie snippet](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/sZ4kbyWcRcWRNNw5BvZ3Cw/55).

Now, the problem with this approach is that you may inadvertently cause an infinite loop: if you don't `.take(30)` the call to `mkString` will never terminate. If you prefer to have a strict collection, you can use the `range` method, which is defined, among others, on `List`s, by first producing a range of integers and then adding each item in the range to your starting date, as in the following alternative example:

```
import java.time.LocalDate

def days(start: LocalDate, end: Long): List[LocalDate] =
  List.range(0, end, step = if (end < 0) -1 else 1).map(start.plusDays)

val startingDate = LocalDate.parse("2020-08-20")

val output = days(start = startingDate, end = -30).mkString(",")

// output is the same as in the previous example
```

Here you can find the documentation for [`List.range`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html#range%5BA%5D(start:A,end:A,step:A)(implicitevidence$4:Integral%5BA%5D):CC%5BA%5D) (you'll easily understand why I passed `step` as I did reading the documentation and maybe playing a bit around with [this snippet on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/sZ4kbyWcRcWRNNw5BvZ3Cw/65)).

Note that you can use the same approach (the `range` method) with `Iterator`s and other lazy sequences as well.

A few resources on lazy vs. strict and mutable vs. immutable collections:

- [What's the difference between LazyList and Stream in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60128207/whats-the-difference-between-lazylist-and-stream-in-scala)
- [Difference between Iterator and Stream in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527962/difference-between-iterator-and-stream-in-scala)
- [Background: Lazy vs Strict Collections](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2017/11/28/view-based-collections.html) in the "Let them be lazy!" blog post

Answer (score 0):

```scala
import java.time.LocalDate

def previousDatesStr(startingDateStr: String, range: Int): String = {
    val startingDate = LocalDate.parse(startingDateStr)
    Range(0, range).map(d => startingDate.minusDays(d)).mkString(", ")
}
```

Other answers are great. but try to use as less java library as possible. since you are using scala.